# Игнорировать совпадение регулярки внутри регулярки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно при помощи регулярки найти "мультилайновые" комментарии кода по типо `/**/`.

Написал регулярку `\/\*(?:.*|\s*)\*\/` ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/g29GkU/1)), в целом работает, но если попадается комментарий внутри комментария, то регулярка учитывает только тот, что "глубже"
[image]

Как можно игнорировать регулярку в регулярке?

Comment: Между двумя открывающими `/*` могут быть непробельные символы? Уровень вложенности ограничен? И правильно ли я понимаю, что внутри могут быть отдельно символы `*` и `/`?

Comment: Возможно я не понял задачу, но замечу, что многострочные комментарии в коде выделяются достаточно примитивно. Комментарий начинается с `/*` и заканчивается первыми же символами `*/`. Т.е. в конструкции `/*/**/*/` комментарием считается `/*/**/`. Если задача в этом, то это выглядит так: https://regex101.com/r/jPtmTx/1

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, хотел расписать как и что, но раз я отталкивался от текстовых редакторов с подсветкой синтаксиса, то решил проверить работу моего примера в них. Допустим *Sublime Text 3* не игнорирует ничего внутри, а работает как ваш код - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/GjsoiaS.png). Скорее всего регуляркой сделать так как хотелось бы - не выйдет, нужен другой подход.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, оформите ваш комментарий как ответ, выберу его правильным)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Выборка комментариев в коде

Если задача найти многострочные комментарии, как это делает компилятор (и редактор кода, соответственно), то решение кажется простым:

`/\/\*.*?\*\//gs` [Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/jPtmTx/1)

Суть: после открытия `/*` мы реагируем на первую же `*/`.
И это работает замечательно.
Но есть нюансы.
**Первый.** Если комментарий открыт, но нет закрывающего тега, то следует выделить всё до конца текста. Исправляемся:

`/\/\*.*?(?:\*\/|$)/gs`

**Второй.** Если конструкция `/**/` встречается в строковых константах (заключенная в кавычки), то такие конструкции также будут выделены.
Любопытно то, что открытый комментарий закроется на теге `*/` даже в том случае, если тег будет заключен в кавычки.
Вот демонстрация сказанного:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что использование этих тегов в строковых константах в явном виде, в принципе, плохая практика.
А стало быть и вероятность встретить это в коде - очень мала.

Тем не менее, учесть это в одной регулярке дело очень желанное.
Итак, выборке подлежат строковые константы и комментарии.
РВ для выделения строк в одинарных кавычках, включая экранированные: `'(?:\\.|[^\\'])*(?:'|$)`
Выделяем аналогично: или до закрывающей кавычки, или до конца текста (об этом еще скажем).

Руководствуясь принципом "кто первый открылся, того и символы", можно составить такое выражение:

```
/\/\*.*?(?:\*\/|$)|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*(?:"|$)|'(?:\\.|[^\\'])*(?:'|$)/gs
```

Понятно, что результат будет содержать как комментарии, так и строки в кавычках. Нам нужно просто отфильтровать выборку по первому символу. Если `/`, значит комментарий.

Ну и для полной картины нужно добавить однострочные комментарии `//`:

```
/\/\*.*?(?:\*\/|$)|\/\/[^\n]+?\n|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*(?:"|$)|'(?:\\.|[^\\'])*(?:'|$)/gs
```

**Нюанс третий.** В одних языках поддерживается задание multi-line строк, а в других нет, либо для этого предусмотрены специальные конструкции (как обратные кавычки в JS).
От этого зависит, как редактор кода будет выделять строки и комментарии.

РВ выше хорошо работает, например для PHP.
Если язык поддерживает задание только single-line строк, то нужно изменить условие выделения строковых констант (до конца строки, а не текста):

```
/\/\*.*?(?:\*\/|$)|\/\/[^\n]+?\n|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*?(?:"|\n)|'(?:\\.|[^\\'])*?(?:'|\n)/gs
```

В JS задать multi-line строку можно с помощью символа переноса `\`, либо с помощью обратных кавычек. Первое уже учтено в РВ, а второй вариант следует добавить:

```
/\/\*.*?(?:\*\/|$)|\/\/[^\n]+?\n|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*?(?:"|\n)|'(?:\\.|[^\\'])*?(?:'|\n)|`(?:\\.|[^\\`])*?(?:`|$)/gs
```

Тестировал с Notepad++ и Visual Studio Code. Конечно, могут быть еще нюансы.
Люди рекомендуют использовать парсер для таких задач.

#### Иерархическая выборка (вложенные совпадения)

Как известно, `RegEx` в JavaScript не поддерживает рекурсию.
Выходом из этого положения может служить [эта библиотека](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp).

А что можно сделать с нативным RegEx?
Разберем ситуацию с односимвольными тегами, например, `{` и `}`.
Условие для выборки самого глубокого элемента в иерархии очень простое: элемент не содержит внутри себя тегов { и }:
`{[^{}]*}` [Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/5fruFp/1)
Условие для выборки родительского элемента схожее. Он содержит в себе дочерний элемент, а между собственными тегами и дочерними исключены иные:
`{[^{}]*{[^{}]*}[^{}]*}` [Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/5fruFp/2)

*Обобщение*
Пусть L - открывающий тег, R - закрывающий тег, # - условие на содержимое элемента.
Тогда обобщенная схема будет выглядеть так:

```
L0                  L # R
L1              L # L # R # R
L2          L # L # L # R # R # R
L3      L # L # L # L # R # R # R # R
..                  .....
```

А полное регулярное выражение для "рекурсивной" выборки с уровнем вложенности n:
**Pn = L0|L1|L2|L3|...|Ln**
(уровни считаем от глубины)

[Проверка P3](https://regex101.com/r/5fruFp/3)

**Многосимвольные теги.** Здесь по другому выглядит условие на содержимое элемента:
`(?:.(?<!L))*?`, где L - левый тег.
Нужно добавить модификатор `s`. Дальше всё по схеме.

[Проверка P0](https://regex101.com/r/5fruFp/4) / [Проверка P3](https://regex101.com/r/5fruFp/5)

Таким образом, c нативным RegEx мы можем делать иерархические выборки с известным уровнем вложенности, для ограниченного круга задач.
И как видим, с каждым уровнем этот монстр растёт.
Надеюсь, кому-то информация будет полезна.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ)